# Hypothesis testing for binomial probability of rain--too low/high?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

**Here is a problem**

The probability there is heavy rain at least once in a week in a region is thought to be 0.7 for any given week.
Over a period of 52 consecutive weeks, there is heavy rain in the following thirteen weeks:

```
1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
```

a - Assuming this probability to be true, find the probability that there is heavy rain in more than one week out of four consecutive weeks.

b - By considering the weeks independently, perform a hypothesis test at the 5% significance level to test if 0.7 is **too low** an estimate for the probability of heavy rain in any week. Make sure to state your hypotheses clearly.

c - By considering the weeks in thirteen groups of four consecutive weeks, perform a hypothesis test at the 5% significance level to test if your answer to part a) is **too high** an estimate for the probability there is heavy rain in more than one week in any four-week period. Make sure to state your hypotheses clearly.

**Here is what I have tried**

For (a), $0.7^4=0.2401$.

For (b),
$X \sim B(52,0.7)$,

$$ H_0: p=0.7, \quad H_1: p<0.7 (????) $$

Then

$$
P(X \leq 13) = 2.89*10^{-11} \quad < \quad 0.05,
$$
which is significantly less than 5%. Hence there is significant evidence to reject $H_0$. But is this the correct **understanding** of the phrase **too low**.

Now for (c), how do I undestand this **too high**? How does that compare to answer in (a)? I am a bit confused.

Start with $X \sim B(13,0.7^4)$,

$$ H_0: p=0.7^4, \quad H_1: p>0.7^4 \quad (\text{????  not sure}) $$

$$
P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P( X=0 ) = 0.971826... 
$$
or
$$
P(X<1) = P( X=0 ) = 0.0238173...
$$
How do I answer this question here, compared to (a), too high and the 5% level ect?? I am fully confused by these words here and trying to understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for showing your work. I guess (b) is intended to make you think about framing alternative hypotheses. // The test you did is reasonable, but I don't think it's the one requested in the problem. // With help on (a) and (b), I will let you deal with (c) on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments and some computations in R to get you started. In R `pbinom` denotes a binomial CDF and `dbinom` denotes a PDF.

(a) $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 4, p = .7).$ You seek 
$P(Y > 1) = 1 - P(X \le 1) = 0.9163.$

```
1 - pbinom(1, 4, .7)
[1] 0.9163

y = 0:4;  pdf = dbinom(y, 4, .7)
plot(y, pdf, type="h", ylim=c(0,max(pdf)), lwd=2,
      ylab="PDF", main = "PDF of BINOM(4,.7)")
  abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

(b) If there is a 70% chance of rain in any one week then we'd expect something near 36 or 37
rainy weeks out of 52. But we observed only 13 rainy weeks. So the 70% probability seems
too *high.*

Let $X$ be the number of rainy days in $n = 52$ weeks.
Test null hypothesis $H_0: p = .7;$ alternative hypothesis
$H_a: p > .7.$

The 'null distribution' is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=52,p=0.7).$
Observed $X = 13.$ Intuitively, we have no evidence the 70% probability
is too *low.* So we do not reject $H_0$ against the alternative that
the probability should be even higher.

P-value is the probability under $H_0$ of an
outcome as extreme or more extreme (in the direction of $H_a)$ than observed.

Formally, $P(X \ge 13\,|\,p=.7) = 1 -P(X \le 12) \approx 1,$ which is not smaller than 5%,
so no rejection of the null hypothesis.

```
1 - pbinom(12, 52, .7)
[1] 1
```

[image]

Unless your instructor or text has put some emphasis on using technology to compute
binomial probabilities, I suppose you are expected to compute the P-value in (b) by using the normal approximation to binomial distributions.  The probability computation in (a)
is easy enough to do on a calculator using the formula for the binomial PDF.

Comment: Looking at your answer, I realised that my (a) is WRONG...now it makes much more sense. I was way too tired when I did it!!

Comment: Am I right to understand that, 13/52 <<0.7, so the 0.7 is 'too high'? I mistook it for '0.7' should be more, so we get 'np' to be something close to 35 (or 36) ...

Comment: OK. I have read and read it again. And I think I finally got my head around with the wording now.

Comment: Happy, if I nudged you onto the right track. Curious, perhaps intentionally tricky, problem.

Comment: Kind of embarrassing as I do have a PhD in Statistics lol.